# SQL Server : filter by year

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mittelwert3 
    @kID INT, @date DATE
AS
    SELECT 
        SUM(((Verkauf.MengePräsentkorb * Präsentkorb.Preis) + 
             (Verkauf.MengeArtikel * Artikel.Preis)) / 365) 
    FROM 
        Verkauf
    INNER JOIN 
        kunde ON kunde.KundeID = Verkauf.KundeID
    INNER JOIN 
        Artikelverkauf ON Artikelverkauf.BestellungID = Verkauf.kaufID
    INNER JOIN 
        Artikel ON Artikel.ArtikelID = Artikelverkauf.ArtikelID
    INNER JOIN 
        Präsentkorbverkauf ON Präsentkorbverkauf.BestellungID = Verkauf.kaufID
    INNER JOIN 
        Präsentkorb ON Präsentkorb.PräsentkorbID = Präsentkorbverkauf.PräsentkorbID
    WHERE 
        kunde.kundeID = @kID 
        AND verkauf.datum = '@date-%%-%%'
```

How is it possible to filter with date year?

Because what I tried doesn't work (see last line of query)

LePlay

Comment: Just don't use the accepted answer in the duplicate. Use the one that uses `>=` and `<` sytnax.

Answer (score 1):

Giving a range is the best option.
These calculations will get the first day of the parameter's year and the first day of the next one. The zero can be changed to any value, but it needs to be constant.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mittelwert3 @kID int ,@date date
AS
SELECT SUM(((Verkauf.MengePräsentkorb*Präsentkorb.Preis)+ 
    (Verkauf.MengeArtikel*Artikel.Preis))/365) 
FROM Verkauf
INNER JOIN kunde ON kunde.KundeID = Verkauf.KundeID
INNER JOIN Artikelverkauf ON Artikelverkauf.BestellungID = Verkauf.kaufID
INNER JOIN Artikel ON Artikel.ArtikelID = Artikelverkauf.ArtikelID
INNER JOIN Präsentkorbverkauf ON Präsentkorbverkauf.BestellungID = Verkauf.kaufID
INNER JOIN Präsentkorb ON Präsentkorb.PräsentkorbID = Präsentkorbverkauf.PräsentkorbID
WHERE kunde.kundeID = @kID 
AND verkauf.datum >= DATEADD( YY, DATEDIFF( YY, 0, @date), 0)
AND verkauf.datum < DATEADD( YY, DATEDIFF( YY, 0, @date)+1, 0)
```

Comment: Got it already with YEAR() function

but Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Using YEAR() function will make the query non-SARGable and eventually cause performance problems.